# Listen RabbitMQ queue in Flask view

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a view in which i send one message (request id) to workers. Then i need to listen result queue and return response only when i received a response msg (The response must contain this msg). How do i do it correctly?

This is my code:

```
def get(self):
    ruid = rand_ruid()
    # add msg to q1
    write_ch = current_app.amqp_conn.channel()
    write_ch.queue_declare(queue='q1', durable=True)
    msg = mkmsg(ruid=ruid)
    write_ch.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='q1', body=msg)
    write_ch.close()

    # then wait results from qbus
    listen_ch = current_app.amqp_conn.channel()
    listen_ch.exchange_declare(exchange='exbus', type='direct')
    listen_ch.queue_declare(queue='bus')

    listen_ch.queue_bind(exchange='exbus', queue='bus', routing_key=ruid)
    while 1:
        for method, properties, body in listen_ch.consume('bus'):
            if method and body:
                listen_ch.basis_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
                listen_ch.close()
                return make_response(body)
```

**Updated**
My question is incorrect, as my approach. I wanted to do asynchronous action (waiting for result from the queue) in synchronous part of the program (flask view).

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py or this https://github.com/eandersson/amqp-storm/blob/master/examples/flask_threaded_rpc_client.py is helpful?